# $scope.$watch is not triggered when ng-model is undefined?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Problem:**

---

I am trying to use `$scope.$watch` method over a ng-model used in a number input with strict attributes like, `max`, `min`, `maxlength` and `step`.

When the value inserted in the input exceeds any of those attributes, the ng-model retrieves `undefined`.

So, eventually, what happens is: `$scope.$watch` is triggered every time we change value in the input. Once the value is undefined, it will only be triggered again when the inserted value is again **valid**, in other words, following attribute rules (max, min, maxlength and step).

---

**E.g.**

*user input:* -2,4
-> `$scope.$watch` is triggered, and outputs, `newValue` as `undefined`.

*user adds a new digit:* -2,44
-> `$scope.$watch` is not triggered anymore, this way.

---

**main.js**

---

```
$scope.$watch("user.input.base.sphere", function(newValue, oldValue) {
console.log(newValue);
}
```

---

**index.html

---

```
<input
ng-cloak
type="number"
ng-class="user.settings.input.sphere.class"
autocomplete="off"
required     
name="sphere"
id="in-sphere"
title="Sphere"
step="{{user.filter.sphere.step}}"
min="{{user.filter.sphere.min}}"
max="{{user.filter.sphere.max}}"
maxlength="{{user.filter.sphere.maxlength}}"
placeholder="{{user.filter.sphere.placeholder}}"
ng-model="user.input.base.sphere" 
select-on-click
sphere>
```

---

**Question:** How can I still let `$scope.$watch` to be triggered even over a undefined `ng-model`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach the following function to the `ng-keyup` directive. This function will get a reference to your form control and read the value that the user has typed in even though the value in the model has not yet been updated.

```
$scope.changeHandler = function (a) {
  var element = angular.element(document.querySelector('#in-sphere'))[0];
  console.log(element.value);
}
```

Attach it to your form control with this:
`ng-keyup='changeHandler()'`

[Here is a working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/yKOBK8hh598AzPuk40RB?p=preview)

Comment: That will be very helpful, thank you, as well for taking your time to write down an example, it's very kind from you

Comment: I must point out, sadly, after creating this method, the execution time is longer than it was before. However, it works at this point